# Error in installing Zend Framework 2 MongoDB DoctrineMongoODMModule

Tags: zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I am getting below error while installing doctrine `DoctrineMongoODMModule`

> **RuntimeException**
>     `/home/angle/public_html/whatsyourlocal/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-m
>     odule` does not exist and could not be created.

Comment: Did you properly install `DoctrineMongoODMModule` via composer? Maybe try another `composer update`. It appears it wasn't installed correctly. Just try again ;)

Comment: yes i am installing module using composer